# Talend - Why are my tJava and tJavaRow components firing out of sequence

Tags: java, talend

[image: Talend]

I am trying to test variable scoping and passing variables to jobjets and subjobs.

What I don't understand in this test job with a a joblet is why I am seeing

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4 - Last Item in Parent Job
```

After I am seeing in my output:

```
In Joblet...
{concurrentHashMap={}, tRowGenerator_1_SUBPROCESS_STATE=0}
```

When tJavaRow_2 in the parent job on the left is in the flow BEFORE the joblet. And my List is being output as part of the tJava_1 component in the jobjet, so logically you would think would be executed after tJavaRow_2.  In the joblet tJava_1 looks like this:

```
System.out.println("In Joblet...");

System.out.println(globalMap.toString());

List<String> myTestList = (ArrayList<String>) globalMap.get("testList");
```

My tJavaRow_2 code is as below:

```
List<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();
              testList.add("Item 1");
              testList.add("Item 2");
              testList.add("Item 3");
              testList.add("Item 4 - Last Item in Parent Job");

              for(String item : testList)
              {

                System.out.println(item);
              }

              globalMap.put("testList", testList);

              System.out.println("Exiting....");
```

i

Comment: You should use tJavaRow in the joblet because tJava will be executed only once per SUBJOB. tJavaRow will be executed once per ROW. And because tJava stuff will be in the _begin part, it will be executed right after your tRowGenerator, generated the first record, but before tJavaRow read it.  Just check the code if you don't believe me.

Comment: Thanks...I believe you, I just don't understand why the sequencing is this illogical?  So you cant really execute tJava in a data flow and have any control over when it fires other than using onComponentOK to force it to fire after a component has completed?

Comment: This link seems to suggest you can run a tJava more than once per subjob, using an iterate?  http://bekwam.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/to-iterate-or-flow-in-talend-open.html